# DevTools failed to load SourceMap error in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm a complete beginner in javascript and I  when I try to run my js code using `inspect` on my web page I get the error

[image]

which I do not understand why exists and if I `console.log("something ")`it shows up on my screen with this error like nothing happened . I would appreciate your help with guiding me to remove it since I am a complete beginner .  Thank you in advance

Comment: That is not an error and it's not related to your code. It comes from an extension.

Comment: That's for AdBlock, has nothing to do with your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Follow two instruction **firstly:**

[image]

Caveat: It is not sticky. You have to reset it every time you open DevTools.

Caveat: API calls to other domains won't show any errors as they belong to a different context.

**Secondly:**
Open Developer Tools, go to "Settings" for Developer Tools, then uncheck Enable JavaScript Sourcemaps under the "Sources" settings.
[image]